# Any as past participle adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Can I use the word *any* as an adverb to modify past participle?
I've heard phrases like:

> Is it **any** good?

Can I make the following sentence by analogy:

> Are these coins **any** valued by collectors?

Comment: I've only really heard 'any' used as an adverb in the construction 'any good?', to express that the speaker is doubtful. In the second example you might want to say 'Are these coins valued at all/ somewhat / to some extent by collectors?'

Comment: "Are these coins any value for collectors" may be closer to what you mean.

Comment: In "Is it any good?", "any" is not an adverb but a determinative functioning as a degree modifier. But "any" can't generally modify verbs so your second example is ungrammatical.

Comment: @AricFowler - Shouldn't it be "**of** any value for [coin] collectors"?

Comment: @Ropey it should, but it is common to leave the word "of" out.

Answer (score 1):

> In "Is it any good?", "any" is not an adverb but a determinative functioning as a degree modifier. But "any" can't generally modify verbs so your second example is ungrammatical.
>
> [BillJ](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139080/any-as-past-participle-adverb#comment282940_139080)